# Grails request parameters encoding issue in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, character-encoding, grails-orm

My grails app will not decode request parameters correctly.

In config.groovy:

- `grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"`
- `grails.converters.encoding =
  "UTF-8"`

All my gsp's use `contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` on the page directive as well as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in the head element.

However, when i receive the posted parameters from the param object in my controller, the app just prints garbage...

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 version deployed over Tomcat 5. Other installed plugins except tomcat:

hibernate 1.3.7
jquery 1.7.1
spring-security-core 1.2.6
webxml 1.4

EDIT: From further debugging, i've noticed that the app will run fine in jetty. Therefore i suspect it must be a tomcat issue. My issue is similar [to this post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/UTF-8-issues-tomcat-vs-jetty-behaving-differently-td1386332.html) (alas i'm not using the Shiro plugin).

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Is the content in the database garbage, or only what's printed out? Do you have the webxml plugin installed (run `grails list-plugins --installed`)?

Comment: from further debugging the problem is in the web tier. The submitted values by the time they reach the controller they are already garbage.

Comment: My installed plugins are: hibernate 1.3.7, tomcat, jquery 1.7.1,          spring-security-core 1.2.6, and webxml 1.4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `URIEncoding='UTF-8'` to the `Connector` elements in conf/server.xml, e.g.

```
<Connector port='8080' protocol='HTTP/1.1' connectionTimeout='20000'
           redirectPort='8443' URIEncoding='UTF-8' />
```

This is described here: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem is with POST parameters actually. If i understood the FAQ correctly URIEncoding applies to GET parameters only. Nevertheless, i gave it a shot but didn't work either. It might be a long shot but could it be the order of filters in my generated web.xml? In there i have the following filters in that order: springSecurityFilterChain -> sitemesh -> charEncodingFilter -> urlMapping -> hiddenHttpMethod -> grailsWebRequest

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that you're using webxml 1.4 - you need to use 1.4.1 which fixes this charEncodingFilter order bug. You also need to upgrade to a later version of Spring Security Core, so you should use 1.2.7.2 (the latest).

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Is there a way to set this `URIEncoding` to `UTF-8` directly in Grails so that we don't have to apply this change to tomcat in each server?

Comment: No, you can't configure the server from inside a war file.

Answer (score 0):

```
edit application.properties
add(update) line:
plugins.webxml=1.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

As fas as no final conclusion made, I'd like to share my expierence in the same situation.
[Here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/UTF8-Character-Encoding-td3661278.html) one can find more discussion.

I my case, I have dev environment under the windows on local pc including local MySQL. Production env - Centos 6, MySQL, Tomcat 6 behind Apache.

In dev environment - everything was o'k, but on production - no.
The only thing that help me - was set  `autoreconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` additionally to recommendations both for Tomcat `URIEncoding='UTF-8'`

So, the problem was in correct settings java Driver for MySQL.