# Form Encoding Problems on GRAILS 2.0

Tags: forms, grails, encoding, utf-8

I have an Grails application that is configured everywhere to function as UTF-8. While running a debug version, headers say `Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8`, and meta tags agree. Browser identified page as UTF-8 and shows characters correctly.

When posting a form, the browser correctly sends it encoded as UTF-8. When reading the data via `params.paramname`, however, the data looks garbled; `maçã` becomes `maÃ§Ã£`.

Upon further inspection, it seems the form is sending UTF-8 data, but Grails seem to try and read it as if it was ISO-8859-1. Setting `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` on the form confirms this problem, as it fixes the problem.

I also have this on applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="characterEncodingFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
    <property name="encoding">
        <value>utf-8</value>
    </property>
    <property name="forceEncoding">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there an solution for this besides adding `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` to all forms in the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you encounter the same problem as in [Grails request parameters encoding issue in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179574/grails-request-parameters-encoding-issue-in-tomcat) - either Burt's answer or comments to it should help.