# Grails spaces decoded as plus signs if parameter text is ASCII

Tags: grails, character-encoding, ascii, http-post

I have a problem in my production Grails app with decoding POST request parameters.

Whenever a parameter contains ASCII characters only, all the spaces in the text are decoded as '+' signs. So, instead of  '***this is a test***' controller gets '***this+is+a+test***' parameter value.

More to that,  **if the parameter text contains even a single non ASCII character**, say, we replace latin 'a' with cyrillic 'a', **the problem is gone**.

And yes, everything is Ok while running application on Windows 7 development machine in Intellij Idea IDE 11.x or as a war archive deployed to standalone local Tomcat 7.0.29.

The production app is deployed as war archive with all dependencies to Ubuntu/Tomcat 7.0.21 on SSL connector port 8443. The connector is configured with attribute *URIEncoding="UTF-8"*

The settings in Config.groovy are

- grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
- grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
- grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = true

All gsp's have meta declaration *http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"* in the head element.

The application plugins are *webxml:1.4.1*, *tomcat:$grailsVersion*, *hibernate:$grailsVersion*, *spring-security-core:1.2.7.3*, *spring-security-openid:1.0.4*

As a last attempt I tried to upgrade Grails version from 2.2.0 to the latest 2.2.2 but no result.

It seems my case is opposite to many others like these

- [Grails request parameters encoding issue in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179574/grails-request-parameters-encoding-issue-in-tomcat)
- http://9exception.com/question/168139
- [Form Encoding Problems on GRAILS 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856493/form-encoding-problems-on-grails-2-0)
- [Grails not encoding the unicode characters properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511497/grails-not-encoding-the-uniocde-characters-properly)

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `grails.views.gsp.encoding` should be set to HTML to prevent HTML injection.

Comment: Did some http traffic analysis with WireShark to exclude browsers fault. In all cases spaces are encoded as '+' signs.
For ASCII there are ...&personalName=for+tests+only&...
For non ASCII there are ...&personalName=f%D0%9Er+tests+only&...

Answer (score 3):

I've finally solved the space problem by upgrading Tomcat version from 7.0.21 to 7.0.39. No application files have been modified.