# Grails not able to decode the unicode characters

Tags: grails

I have following configurations for a Grails app:

1. Grails 1.3.7
    Set the following in the config.groovy file
    `grails.views.default.codec="none"`
    `grails.views.gsp.encoding="UTF-8"`
    `grails.converters.encoding="UTF-8"`
2. Tomcat 7.0.22
   Set the following in the server.xml file for tomcat
   `URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"`

And, in my gsp page, I've set `charset=UTF-8"` since I want to use the UTF-8 character encoding.

Then, in any of the input box when I enter a unicode character and submit the form and check for the parameter dump at the associated action in the controller, the unicode character is garbled. Checking the browser request to the server using the Firebug shows the unicode character being correctly encoded and submitted to the server.

But still, if I do sth. like
`params.unicodeInput = new String(params.unicodeInput.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF8");`

the unicode character is correctly decoded. I wanted to know why the unicode characters are not being correctly decoded on a normal browser request although the browser correctly sends the unicode characters.

Thanks!!

**Edit**
I created a demo app with the same configuration and everything seems fine on the demo app. This problem exists only in this particular app. Could it be due to some other installed plugins?

And printing the `request.getCharacterEncoding()` and `response.getCharacterEncoding()` both yields to UTF-8.

Comment: When you say "parameter dump" what are you doing exactly? Printing Unicode characters to the console is not necessarily going to work correctly, depending on your OS.

Comment: I just `println` the `params` map. I use Ubuntu and STS for development and have no problem displaying the unicode characters in the ide console. And as I've mentioned, manually changing the character encoding for the parameter like `params.unicodeInput = new String(params.unicodeInput.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF8");` and then printing the decoded character yields to the actual character in the console.

Comment: Had the same issue with Tomcat (worked like a charm in Jetty though). Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179574/grails-request-parameters-encoding-issue-in-tomcat

Comment: @lefty Actually I did see your post before posting this one. My plugins are same as yours except that I don't use webxml plugin. And I can't upgrade the Spring Security Core plugin. Mine version is 1.1.3. and alas I am not in the position to upgrade the plugin (I'm working on a legacy app and I don't have the authority for such upgrades.). So any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue. For some reason, any "show" gsp/controller method shows "?", but the "edit" always shows the correct UTF-8 char.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, but when I had unicode problems with Grails + Tomcat, I solved the problem adding the following parameters to Tomcat's setenv.sh:
`JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`